# The following recursive function defines a linear affine difference equation?

Tags: recursion

I am trying to solve this example:

The following recursive function defines a linear affine difference equation
$$x(n+1) = 1.4*x(n) + 0.2$$
$$x(0) = -1$$

1. Find the first three values of the iteration?
2. Which initial value y(0) would cause the iteration to remain constant?

Can you give me a hint how to calculate this quickly?(For example by using wolfram alpha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $1.4^ny(n)=x(n)$, then the equation becomes
$$
1.4^{n+1}y(n+1)=1.4^{n+1}y(n)+0.2\tag{1}
$$
Then you get
$$
y(n+1)=y(n)+0.2(1.4)^{-n-1}\tag{2}
$$
which becomes
$$
y(n)=0.2\sum_{k=1}^n1.4^{-k}+y(0)\tag{3}
$$
We can use the standard sum of a geometric series to get
$$
\begin{align}
y(n)
&=0.2\frac{1.4^{-1}-1.4^{-n-1}}{1-1.4^{-1}}+y(0)\\
&=0.2\frac{1-1.4^{-n}}{0.4}+y(0)\\
&=\frac12(1-1.4^{-n})+y(0)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x(n)
&=\frac12(1.4^n-1)+1.4^nx(0)\\
&=1.4^n\left(\frac12+x(0)\right)-\frac12\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

1. We can easily compute the first few terms using $(5)$ and $x(0)=-1$.
2. If $x(0)=-\frac12$, then we get from $(5)$ that $x(n)=-\frac12$ for all $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 1):

For part 2):

If $x(0)=x(1)$ then $x(0)=x(1)=1.4x(0)+0.2$, thus $x(0)=\frac{-1}{2}$

Comment: it is correct now.